# How to configure WordPress redirection

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, bitnami

When I access `domain.com`, I can see top page with URL `domain.com`.
If I update the page, it will be redirected like the URL will be `origin.domain.com`.

I would like to fix it to `domain.com`.

Also, I am setting `origin.domain.com` on `HOME_URL` and `SITE_URL` of WordPress by `wp-config.php`.

This is my current environment:

```
User 
 -> domain.com by HTTPS 
   -> Cloud Front 
     -> subdomain.domain.com by HTTPS
       -> ELB 
         -> subdomain.domain.com by HTTP 
           -> EC2 (WordPress with bitnami)
```

CloudFront and ELB have certificates, but EC2 does not.

I guess I have to fix `HOST` or something to get correct response?

Comment: What is the "correct response" you're expecting? You want the site to load on `domain.com` right? What happens now when you go to `domain.com`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I would like the site to load on domain.com.

When I go to domain.com, I can see top page "domain.com".
But if I try to go to other page like "domain.com/products", the URL will be "origin.domain.com/products".

Comment: What happens if you set `HOME_URL` & `SITE_URL` in `wp-config.php` to `domain.com`?

Comment: If I set HOME_URL & SITE_URL in wp-config.php to domain.com,
I can access TOP page first and admin dashboard of wordpress by "domain.com/wp-admin".
Also, I can see the same URL in settings of WordPress.

But why can I see the website now? I guess I am accessing origin.domain.com now according to the configuration below.


Route53
domain.com -> cloudfront(ALIAS)
origin.domain.com -> ELB(ALIAS)

User 
 -> domain.com by HTTPS 
   -> Cloud Front 
     -> subdomain.domain.com by HTTPS
       -> ELB 
         -> subdomain.domain.com by HTTP 
           -> EC2 (WordPress)